# Android - calculate arc angle

Tags: android, math, canvas, android-canvas, ondraw

I have an arc and i wish to draw scale marks at 0, 45, 90, 135, 180 degrees, can anyone help me with the math needed to achive the x,y of points 5 and 30 on this sketch?:

[image]

here is my code for drawing the 1 scale mark.

```
   private void drawScale(Canvas canvas) {
        //canvas.drawOval(scaleRect, scalePaint);

        canvas.save();

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        p.setStrokeWidth(10f);
        canvas.drawLine(rectF.left-getWidth()/20, rectF.height()/2, rectF.left, rectF.height()/2, p);


    canvas.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can calculate its rotation using `sin` and `cos`. Lets assume that you have zero point `A` and want to rotate it to point `B` which is rotated for 30°. 
Something like this:

[image]

Basically new point is at `(cx+x,cy+y)`. In this particular case definition of `sin` and `cos` would be next:

```
sin = x/R
cos = y/R
```

It is not hard to get exact `x` and `y`. So to rotate point on particular angle in circle with know radius we need to calculate coordinates in next way:

```
x = cx + sin(angle) * R; 
y = cy + cos(angle) * R;
```

Now lets get back to Android and Canvas!

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    float cx = getWidth() / 2f;
    float cy = getHeight() / 2f;

    float scaleMarkSize = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 16; // 16dp
    float radius = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += 45) {
        float angle = (float) Math.toRadians(i); // Need to convert to radians first

        float startX = (float) (cx + radius * Math.sin(angle));
        float startY = (float) (cy - radius * Math.cos(angle));

        float stopX = (float) (cx + (radius - scaleMarkSize) * Math.sin(angle));
        float stopY = (float) (cy - (radius - scaleMarkSize) * Math.cos(angle));

        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, scalePaint);
    }

    canvas.restore();
}
```

Code will draw marks with step of 45°. Note you need to convert angle to radians and for Y axis I used minus cause on canvas it is flipped. Here is what I have got:

[image]

Comment: Nice, you could make it a bit tidier by using [`Canvas.translate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate(float,%20float)) to set the center, then you can forget about it. It looks like you thought about it, because you `save` and `restore` canvas matrix.

Comment: `canvas.translate(-cx,-cy)`; Then drop all other references to `cx`,`cy`

Comment: @andrew The lines are drawing upside down. What should I do if I want to draw the line from bottom to up
See the sample image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhrgK.png

Comment: @android not sure what you mean, try to play with radius or flip `startX, startY, stopX, stopY`

Answer (score 4):

If you know the point at the center of the circle and the radius of the circle it becomes pretty easy if you use vectors to your advantage.

First you're gonna need the unit vectors at each angle

- 0 deg   -> (-1,0)
- 45 deg  -> (-1/sqrt(2), (1/sqrt(2))
- 90 deg  -> (0,1)
- 135 deg -> (1/sqrt(2), (1/sqrt(2))
- 180 deg -> (1,0)

You can then calculate the necessary points using the formula below

```
point = center + (unit vector * distance from center)
```

Here is a more concrete example since andrew added one.

```
private static final float RADIUS = 400.0f;
private static final float MARK_LENGTH = 30.0f;
private static final UnitVector[] UNIT_VECTORS = new UnitVector[] {
        new UnitVector(-1,0), // 0 deg
        new UnitVector((float) (-1/Math.sqrt(2)), (float) (1/Math.sqrt(2))), // 45 deg
        new UnitVector(0, 1), // 90 deg
        new UnitVector((float) (1/Math.sqrt(2)), (float) (1/Math.sqrt(2))), // 135 deg
        new UnitVector(1, 0), // 180 deg
        new UnitVector((float) (1/Math.sqrt(2)), (float) (-1/Math.sqrt(2))), // 225 deg
        new UnitVector(0, -1), // 270 deg
        new UnitVector((float) (-1/Math.sqrt(2)), (float) (-1/Math.sqrt(2))), // 315 deg
};

static class UnitVector {
    final float x;
    final float y;

    UnitVector(final float x, final float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

// Call this from onDraw
public void drawMarks(final Canvas canvas) {
    for (final UnitVector unitVector : UNIT_VECTORS) {
        this.drawMarkWithVector(unitVector, canvas);
    }
}

private void drawMarkWithVector(final UnitVector unitVector, final Canvas canvas) {
    final float centerPointX = this.getWidth() / 2;
    final float centerPointY = this.getHeight() / 2;
    final float startX = centerPointX + (unitVector.x * RADIUS);
    final float startY = centerPointY + (unitVector.y * RADIUS);
    final float endX = centerPointX + (unitVector.x * (RADIUS + MARK_LENGTH));
    final float endY = centerPointY + (unitVector.y * (RADIUS + MARK_LENGTH));
    canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, this.paint);
}
```

Here is the result of the code above
[image: Result of the code]

Comment: First, thank you for your help, second, I am not all that great at this sort of math so if you could please clarify for me:
1. what is the unit vector?
2. what is the point?
3. what is the mark length?
Thank you again for the help

Comment: A simplified way to think a unit vector is to think about it as a line of length one that points in a certain direction. This means if you want to move a point by a certain length in the direction of the unit vector you simply multiply the unit vector by the desired length and add it to the original point. The resulting point is the point i mention in the equation. Some more info here https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vector-unit.html
The mark length is the length of the while lines youre drawing.

Comment: Added a more concrete example since andrew added one. Both methods work well and have their upsides. andrews solution is more versatile and allows you to change the angles at which the marks are drawn. My solution is less computationally expensive since it avoids doing trig math.

Comment: I appreciate your help, i sorry i picked a different answer as the correct one, it is a bit more  compatible with my needs but thank you anyway :)